# In a Blue / Green deployment system, what is each one called?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, naming-conventions, naming, blue-green-deployment

I am working on setting up Blue/Green deployments for my Kubernetes system.  I need to make a variable for which one I am currently on (Blue or Green)

But I don't know what a single one of them is called.  Channel, pipeline, side, part, state, ... ?

**What is one side of the Blue/Green deployment system called?**

Or is there no generally accepted name for this? (maybe I need to call my variable `CurrentBlueGreenStatus`)

Comment: AFAIK, They're called Environment

Comment: @Yayotrón - That is unfortunate.  We use the term "Environments" for Dev, Test, Prod. (IE, the Dev Environment or the Prod Environment.)  That will get confusing if Blue vs Green is also an Environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are basically trying to do here is to "reinventing the wheel".  Blue/Green deployment is just a release concept or model so to me the name is in fact `deployment`, eventually `deploymentType`.  In some cases it's being called `environment`, `app` or even `server`.

> In  [software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_engineering),  **blue-green deployment**  is a method of
> installing changes to a web, app, or database server by swapping
> alternating production and staging servers.